# Sequences that sum up to $\frac{m^{n+1}}{n+1}\binom{2n}{n}{}_2F_1(1,n+\frac{1}{2}; n+2; -4m(m-1))$

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, sequences-and-series, recurrences, closed-form-expressions

Let $a(n,m)$ be an integer sequence such that
$$a(n,m)=\frac{m^{n+1}}{n+1}\binom{2n}{n}{}_2F_1(1,n+\frac{1}{2}; n+2; -4m(m-1))$$
Let
$$\ell(n)=\left\lfloor\log_2 n\right\rfloor$$
$$f(n)=n-2^{\ell(n)}$$
$$g(n)=[n+1\ne 2^k]\cdot(g(\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor)+1), g(0)=0$$
Here square brackets denote Iverson brackets, $f(n)$ is the same as $n$ without the most significant bit and $g(n)$ is [A063250](https://oeis.org/A063250), i.e., number of binary right-rotations to reach fixed point.

Let $b(n,m)$ be an integer sequence such that
$$b(n,m)=m(b(f(n),m)+[g(n)>0]\cdot b(f(n)+2^{g(n)-1},m)), b(0,m)=1$$
Let $s(n,m)$ be an integer sequence such that
$$s(n,m)=\sum\limits_{j=0}^{2^n-1}b(j,m)$$
I conjecture that
$$s(n,m)=a(n+1,m)$$
Is there a way to prove it?